# How to have a stored procedure kick off after the conclusion of my first stored procedure?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a stored procedure that inserts and (combined) takes several hours to run. I noticed that when i split the stored procedure ( 1) hour, day, week  2) month, year); the two stored procedures finish running a lot faster than having it in one massive stored procedure. What is the best solution to have the second stored procedure run after the conclusion of the first procedure? I have looked online for solutions to no avail. I also don't think a trigger would work due to the fact that each of these 'inner case' stored procedures are intended to handle hundreds of inserts. Below is my (watered down) code: Thanks in advance!

Also: if there are any other improvements I can make to my code, any /all feedback is appreciated :)

**Original Code:**

```
create or replace PROCEDURE STORED_PROCEDURE_COMBINED
is
  CURSOR hour IS
                SELECT distinct HOUR as HOUR
                  FROM TABLE
                 WHERE FLAG = 0;
  CURSOR day is
                SELECT distinct day as day
                  FROM TABLE
                 WHERE FLAG = 0;
  l_hr hour%ROWTYPE;
  l_day days%ROWTYPE;         
  INSERT_HOUR(l_hr.hour);
  INSERT_DAY(l_day.day);
  INSERT_WEEK(l_day.day);
  INSERT_MONTH(l_day.day);
  INSERT_YEAR(l_day.day);

END STORED_PROCEDURE_COMBINED;
```

**What I want:**

```
create or replace PROCEDURE STORED_PROCEDURE_1
is
  CURSOR hour IS
                SELECT distinct HOUR as HOUR
                  FROM TABLE
                 WHERE FLAG = 0;
  CURSOR day is
                SELECT distinct day as day
                  FROM TABLE
                 WHERE FLAG = 0;
  l_hr hour%ROWTYPE;
  l_day days%ROWTYPE;         
  INSERT_HOUR(l_hr.hour);
  INSERT_DAY(l_day.day);
  INSERT_WEEK(l_day.day);
 END STORED_PROCEDURE_1;
```

***The Procedure Above Kicks off the Procedure below after completion:***

```
create or replace PROCEDURE STORED_PROCEDURE_2
is
  CURSOR day is
                SELECT distinct day as day
                  FROM TABLE
                 WHERE FLAG = 0;
  l_day days%ROWTYPE;
  INSERT_MONTH(l_day.day);
  INSERT_YEAR(l_day.day);

END STORED_PROCEDURE_2;
```

Comment: Why can't the first procedure just call the second before it ends? I'm not sure why splitting would be any faster though as it's doing exactly the same work; unless your combined one is actually repeating something much more often than you expect accidentally, or something else that you're only incidentally fixing. You haven't shown the actual cursor loops so it's not really clear.

Comment: agree with Alex.  Are you sure you just are not repeating one of your cursors every iteration of another cursor?  Also do you need a cursor at all is there a set based way of doing what you are needing to do?

Comment: I'm not sure either. maybe i am repeating the cursors. But in this case, i have a complex system set up where the cursor is picking up any hour (or day); rounding that hour to the nearest week/month/year (after the dailies are finished) and inserting them as parameters to be included in the where clause in the 'inner-case' stored procedures (if that makes sense).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
create or replace PROCEDURE STORED_PROCEDURE_COMBINED
is
  STORED_PROCEDURE_1();
  STORED_PROCEDURE_2();
END STORED_PROCEDURE_COMBINED;
```

Add committing, error checking and exception handling as needed.

Comment: Add a line that says commit;

Comment: where? haha i've already done so within the inner cases. are you talking about after STORED_PROCEDUR_2(); ?

Comment: If you've done so within the wrapped procedures then I wouldn't think you would need to do so again.